# Is it possible to get a StackOverflow error with event-driven recursive actors at all?

Tags: scala, actor

As it's said in the comments, [`Combinatiors.loop`](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//actors/scala/actors/Reactor.scala#L277) of the standard actors library is intended to save you from stack overflows, when the body of an actor is repeatedly executed.

But, does it make any sense to use `loop` for an event-driven actors (`react`), when message handling is, in fact, [almost] always scheduled to be executed in a dedicated thread pool? Simple recursive call of the body seem to be a more efficient option.

---

Method `Reactor.seq` (called by `Combinatiors.loop`) is defined as follows:

```
  private[actors] def seq[a, b](first: => a, next: => b): Unit = {
    val killNext = this.kill
    this.kill = () => {
      this.kill = killNext

      // to avoid stack overflow:
      // instead of directly executing `next`,
      // schedule as continuation
      scheduleActor({ case _ => next }, null)
      throw Actor.suspendException
    }
first
throw new KillActorControl
```

}

Let's assume, `next` is called directly. In this case, `react` is executed immediately, [message handling is scheduled](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src//actors/scala/actors/Reactor.scala#L127), and the actor is suspended. No room for stack overflows...

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loop` is a general-purpose construct, that can be used both for thread-based and event-driven actors. If you try to handle messages of a thread-based actor recursively, you will end up quickly with stack overflow (unless your message handling is tail recursive, and can be optimized).

With regards to event-driven actors, you're absolutely right - recursive handling will be more effective, as long as stack overflow scenario specific for thread-based actors is not valid for event-driven ones (you even shouldn't make the recursion optimizable).